# Python Regex remove space b/w a Bracket and Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Python, I have a string like this, Input:

```
IBNR    13,123   1,234  ( 556 )   ( 2,355 )  934
```

Required output- :

Either remove the space b/w the bracket and number

```
IBNR    13,123   1,234  (556)   (2,355)  934
```

OR Remove the brackets:

```
IBNR   13,123   1,234  556  2,355  934
```

I have tried this:

```
re.sub('(?<=\d)+ (?=\\))','',text1)
```

This solves for right hand side, need help with left side.

Comment: So what do you want? Remove the parentheses around the numbers?

Comment: `re.sub(r'[()]', '', text1)` removes the brackets

Comment: @js-on you don't need to escape the parentheses in the regex

Comment: @retnikt good to know, thanks

Comment: Yes, Either remove the parentheses around the numbers or remove the space b/w the parentheses and number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
import re

data = """IBNR    13,123   1,234  ( 556 )   ( 2,355 )  934 """

def replacer(m):
    return f"({m.group(1).strip()})"

data = re.sub(r'\(([^()]+)\)', replacer, data)
print(data)
# IBNR    13,123   1,234  (556)   (2,355)  934
```

Or remove the parentheses altogether:

```
data = re.sub(r'[()]+', '', data)
# IBNR    13,123   1,234   556     2,355   934
```

As [**@JvdV**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) points out, you might better use

```
re.sub(r'\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)', r'\1', data)
```

Comment: Nice, in the second example OP wants to replace paranthesis and spaces. Maybe adapt your second example a little. Possibly something like: `data = re.sub(r'\(\s*|\s*\)', r'', data)` but I bet that can be done better =)

Comment: @JvdV: Why not, added your example.

Comment: Cool, I changed my example, but not sure if the previous was quicker.

Comment: @JvdV: Probably yes (haven't tested). An alternation is usually slower.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the brackets with this pattern:

```
(\w+\s+\d+,\d+\s+\d+,\d+\s+)\((\s+\d+\s+)\)(\s+)\((\s+\d+,\d+\s)\)(\s+\d+)
```

See the results, including substitutions:

https://regex101.com/r/ch6Jge/1

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use the lookahead at all, but I think it does what you want.

```
re.sub(r'\(\s(\d+(?:\,\d+)*)\s\)', r'\1', text1)
```

Comment: There's no lookahead whatsoever in your expression.

Comment: Sorry, imprecise wording. Not mine but yours.